# Explicit formula for Euler zigzag numbers(Up/down numbers)

Tags: sequences-and-series, co.combinatorics

I have derived an explicit formula for the [Euler zigzag numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerZigzagNumber.html), the number of alternating permutations for n elements:

$$A_n = i^{n+1}\sum _{k=1}^{n+1} \sum _{j=0}^k {k\choose{j}} \frac{(-1)^j(k-2j)^{n+1}}{2^ki^kk}$$

For details, please refer to my article in [Voofie](http://www.voofie.com/):

[An Explicit Formula for the Euler zigzag numbers (Up/down numbers) from power series](http://www.voofie.com/content/117/an-explicit-formula-for-the-euler-zigzag-numbers-updown-numbers-from-power-series/)

I would like to ask, if my formula is new, or is it a well known result? Since I can't find it in Wikipedia or MathWorld. If it is an old formula, can anyone give me some reference to it? Also, if possible, can anyone provide some reference to other explicit formula for $A_n$?

Comment: Could you please put your formula in display mode so that it is legible?  Also, \binom{n}{k} is a much nicer binomial coefficient.

Comment: Also, what is $i$?

Comment: Your formula is too tiny to be really new! :-) Jokes aside, the wolframworld page gives the link to OEIS, http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A000111, from which I see many compact explicit formulas for your (and Euler's, of course) numbers.

Comment: @JBL: $i=\sqrt{-1}$ :-)

Comment: I by no means want to diminish your result, but I'd say it could be new, or known, or already discovered and forgotten several times. Is 8837*93934=830094758 a new result or not? 

Comment: @Wadim Zudilin:
At which session do u refer to? I found none explicit formula in the Formula session. Thank you for your reference.

Comment: Dear everyone,
I found the above formula when I am trying to solve a partial difference equation as an exercise. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33498/solving-partial-difference-equation

The Euler zigzag numbers are secant and tangent number respectively for the even term and odd term, and it is given by $A_0^n$ from the sequence $A_k^n$ from the above link.

I would be very please if anyone can give me some insight in solving the partial difference equation. Thank you.

Comment: It says "Your website is not available" when I click on the second and third links.

Answer (score 2):

Dear Ross,

It looks that you don't really wish to see known formulae
for your zigzag numbers. Otherwise I don't understand why
you found my search insufficient.

The OEIS [A000111](http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A000111) gives the formula
$$
A_m=2^m\biggl|E_m\biggl(\frac12\biggr)+E_m(1)\biggr|
$$
where $E_m(x)$ are the [Euler polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials)
which can be generated by the following explicit expansion
$$
E_m(x)=\sum_{n=0}^m\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom nk(x+k)^m,
$$
a double sum as in your case. Even if this formula is not exactly the same as yours
(although it looks pretty similar), this is a *known* double sum expression for $A_m$.
There is a lot of room for playing with this double sum and producing many other
(useful and useless) formulae for the zigzag numbers.

And don't forget: I've never seen this specific sequence before.

Best wishes,
Wadim

Comment: Wadim, you are right. It is really an explicit formula. I didn't notice it since I don't know Euler polynomials has explicit expansion. However, the formula you provided has an absolute sign. I think it will make all the manipulation and computation inconvenient?

Comment: Ross, who care about having another formula for the same sequence if this is just a new formula without applications or with applications which can be achieved by a known one?!

Comment: $$
A_m=2^m\biggl|E_m\biggl(\frac12\biggr)+E_m(1)\biggr|
$$ In this case, $A_0 =2^0\biggl|1+1\biggr|=2≠1$, Is there wrong with my arithmetic?

Comment: Wadim, can you check out the last comment? Also, I'm not able to find your claimed formula under https://oeis.org/A000111 Thanks.